# How do I share an analysis_options.yaml file across multiple packages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a `Flutter Module`, multiple `Flutter Plugins`. The relationship between them is: `module` depends on all `plugins`. All plugins are not published to pub and use git dependencies.

I now need to add `analysis_options.yaml` to each `plugin`, the configuration is the same. So I have an idea, can all plugins share the `same analysis_options.yaml`? I haven't found a way yet.

`flutter analyze` cannot specify a directory, it is executed in the current project by default, and the `analysis_options.yaml` rule can be applied.
`dart analyze` can specify directories or files, but cannot apply the `analysis_options.yaml` rules. If I want to specify both directory or file scans, but also custom rules, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options:

> If the analyzer can’t find an analysis options file at the package root, it walks up the directory tree, looking for one. If no file is available, the analyzer defaults to standard checks.

So if you want a `analysis_options.yaml` file shared among directories, you can place one in a common parent directory.

You also can make one `analysis_option.yaml` file include another one and then adjust rules.  For example:

```yaml
include: path/to/another/analysis_options.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    avoid_as: false
```