# Code suggestions not working after excluding files from lint

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, yaml

I have set some new lint rules but I don't want lint to be enabled for existing files as we have to change in many places and also testing would required. I just wanted new lint rule should applicable for new files for that I excluded all the existing files from the lint but it disables the inteli-sense and suggestion for excuded files.

How can I disable only lint? instead of analyzer.

I want dart analyzer (code suggestions) should work for excluded files.

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
linter:
  rules:
    always_declare_return_types: true
    always_use_package_imports: true
    avoid_print: true
    cancel_subscriptions: true
    avoid_bool_literals_in_conditional_expressions: true
    avoid_positional_boolean_parameters: true
    avoid_unnecessary_containers: true
    avoid_void_async: true
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: true
    missing_whitespace_between_adjacent_strings: true
    prefer_null_aware_method_calls: true
    prefer_single_quotes: true
    sort_unnamed_constructors_first: true
    unnecessary_lambdas: true
    use_named_constants: true
    use_string_in_part_of_directives: true
    avoid_dynamic_calls: true
    cascade_invocations: true
    cast_nullable_to_non_nullable: true
    comment_references: true
    prefer_collection_literals: true
    prefer_const_constructors: true
    prefer_if_elements_to_conditional_expressions: true
    prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings: true
    sized_box_for_whitespace: true
    use_build_context_synchronously: true
    use_colored_box: true
    use_decorated_box: true
    use_string_buffers: true
    use_super_parameters: true
    use_to_and_as_if_applicable: true
    valid_regexps: true

# https://dartcodemetrics:dev/docs/getting-started/configuration:
dart_code_metrics:
  metrics:
    cyclomatic-complexity: 20
    number-of-parameters: 14
    maximum-nesting-level: 5
    halstead-volume: 150
    lines-of-code: 26

  metrics-exclude:
    - test/**
  rules:
    - newline-before-return:
        severity: warning
    - no-boolean-literal-compare:
        severity: warning
    - no-empty-block:
        severity: warning
    - no-equal-then-else:
        severity: warning
    - avoid-global-state:
        severity: warning
    - avoid-nested-conditional-expressions:
        acceptable-level: 1
        severity: warning

    - avoid-redundant-async:
        severity: warning
    - avoid-unnecessary-type-casts:
        severity: warning
    - avoid-unrelated-type-assertions:
        severity: warning
    - avoid-unused-parameters:
        severity: warning

    - ban-name:
        severity: warning
        entries: #Eg
          - ident: strangeName
            description: The name is too strange

    - member-ordering:
        severity: warning
        order:
          - constructors
          - public-fields
          - private-fields
          - close-method
          - dispose-method
        widgets-order:
          - constructor
          - build-method
          - init-state-method
          - did-change-dependencies-method
          - did-update-widget-method
          - dispose-method

    - no-boolean-literal-compare:
        severity: warning
    - no-equal-arguments:
        severity: warning
    - prefer-correct-identifier-length:
        severity: warning
        exceptions: [ 'exampleExclude' ]
        max-identifier-length: 30
        min-identifier-length: 3

    - prefer-correct-type-name:
        severity: warning
        excluded: [ 'exampleExclude']
        min-length: 3
        max-length: 40


    - prefer-enums-by-name:
        severity: warning
    - prefer-first:
        severity: warning
    - prefer-last:
        severity: warning
    - prefer-moving-to-variable:
        severity: warning
        allowed-duplicated-chains: 3

  anti-patterns:
    - long-method:
        severity: warning
    - long-parameter-list:
        severity: warning
analyzer:
  plugins:
    - dart_code_metrics

  warnings:
    always_declare_return_types: warning
    always_use_package_imports: warning
    avoid_print: warning
    cancel_subscriptions: warning
    avoid_bool_literals_in_conditional_expressions: warning
    avoid_positional_boolean_parameters: warning
    avoid_unnecessary_containers: warning
    avoid_void_async: warning
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: warning
    missing_whitespace_between_adjacent_strings: warning
    prefer_null_aware_method_calls: warning
    prefer_single_quotes: warning
    sort_unnamed_constructors_first: warning
    unnecessary_lambdas: warning
    use_named_constants: warning
    avoid_dynamic_calls: warning
    cascade_invocations: warning
    cast_nullable_to_non_nullable: warning
    comment_references: warning
    prefer_collection_literals: warning
    prefer_const_constructors: warning
    prefer_if_elements_to_conditional_expressions: warning
    prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings: warning
    sized_box_for_whitespace: warning
    use_build_context_synchronously: warning
    use_colored_box: warning
    use_decorated_box: warning
    use_string_buffers: warning
    use_super_parameters: warning
    use_to_and_as_if_applicable: warning
    valid_regexps: warning

  exclude:
    - test/**
    - lib/analytics/events.dart
    - lib/generated/assets.dart
    - lib/generated/locales.g.dart
    - lib/ui/home/home_view.dart
    - lib/ui/home/home_controller.dart
    - lib/ui/home/home_binding.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/campus_manager.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/campus_life.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/learning_guide.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/seniors.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/attendance.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/banner.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/exclusive_event.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/upcoming_event.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/success_stories.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/opportunity.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/time_table.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/login/gmail_login_controller.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/login/canvas_login_controller.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/login/gmail_login_view.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/login/canvas_login_view.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/faculty.dart
    - lib/ui/home/general_cards/placement_partners.dart
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude` section lists files to completely exclude from static analysis.  Without static analysis, nothing about those files will be reported to your IDE.

What you maybe could do instead is to [create separate `analysis_options.yaml` files for those subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71260162/) that enable/disable a different set of lints, or explicitly add appropriate [`ignore_for_file`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#suppressing-rules-for-a-file) lines to  those files.